# msizap.exe reports No product/patch data was found

Tags: windows-7, disk-space-utilization

I was trying to free up some space on my Windows 7 machine and was directed to a utility called msizap.exe from Microsoft which removes orphaned msi's from the c:\windows\installer directory.  My Installer directory is 12Gb on a 1 year old installation.

When I run "msizap.exe g" as an administrator it quickly returns the following.
"
Removing orphaned cached files
No product/patch data was found
"

Nothing seems to have been removed from installer.

Is it possible I have no orphan files or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I agree with cmorse about using msizap (amusingly, autocorrect changed msizap to misapplied.) if you're hurting for disk space, you may want to see how much is allocated to restore points. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-much-disk-space-does-System-Restore-require

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend *not* using msizap on your computer. Microsoft has retired the Windows Installer Cleanup Utility, which included msizap. See Microsoft [kb2438651](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2438651) for more information, specifically this portion of the kb article:

> **Important**: The Windows Installer Cleanup utility (MSICUU2.exe) that was previously referred to in this article has been retired. While the Windows Installer Cleanup utility resolved some installation problems, it sometimes damaged other components installed on the computer. Because of this, the tool has been removed from the Microsoft Download Center. The [Program Install and Uninstall troubleshooter](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall) is a replacement for that utility.